# $L/F$ unramified , $\sigma(L)/\sigma(F)$ it is also unramified

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/K$ be an extension of field, and $F$ be a subfield of $L$ contains $K$ such that the extension $L/F$ is an unramified Galois extension, if $\sigma$ is an isomorphism of $L$ leaving $K$ fixed,

What we can say about the ramification in the extension  $\sigma(L)/\sigma(F)$ ? (it is also unramified ?)

thanks

Comment: @Magdiragdag but $L/K$ not a Galois extension !!

Comment: I just wondered what the codomain of $\sigma$ was. But it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is also unramified. The isomorphism $\sigma$ preserves everything: the rings of integers, the (prime) ideals of the rings of integers, decomposition of ideals in prime ideals. It does everything you can possibly want.

Comment: thank you , if $\frak p'$ a prime of $\sigma(F)$ then there exists a prime ideal $\frak p$ such that $\frak p'=\sigma \frak p$ and $\frak P'$ a prime of $\sigma(K)$ then there exists a prime ideal $\frak P$ such that $\frak P'=\sigma \frak P$ how to prove that $I(\sigma P/\sigma p)=I(\frak P/\frak p)$

Comment: Apply $\sigma^{-1}$ or $\sigma$: ${\frak P}^k \mid {\frak p} O_L \iff \sigma({\frak P})^k \mid \sigma({\frak p})O_{\sigma(L)}$.